# Automatically create rule in Outlook c#

Tags: c#, email, outlook

I need to create a set of rules in Microsoft Outlook via C#.
I have found a lot of documentation online, but unfortunately it is not working for me.

I create the rule using the function below:

```
{
           Outlook.Application  OutlookApplication = Marshal.GetActiveObject("Outlook.Application") as Outlook.Application;

            Outlook.MAPIFolder OutlookInbox = (Outlook.MAPIFolder)OutlookApplication.Application.ActiveExplorer().Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);

            Outlook.Rules rules = null;
            try
            {
                rules = OutlookApplication.Session.DefaultStore.GetRules(); //Gets list of outlook rules
            }
            catch
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Could not obtain rules collection.");
                return;
            }

            string ruleName = "TestRule";

            Outlook.Rule rule = rules.Create(ruleName, Outlook.OlRuleType.olRuleReceive);  //Creates new rule in collection
            rule.Name = ruleName;

            //From condition
            rule.Conditions.From.Recipients.Add("allixhd@gmail.com");
            rule.Conditions.From.Enabled = true;

            //Subject condition
            rule.Conditions.Subject.Text = new string[] { "#test" };
            rule.Conditions.Subject.Enabled = true;

            //Move action   
            Outlook.MAPIFolder ruleFolder = OutlookInbox.Folders["TestFolder"]; //Gets the folder with name TestFolder
            rule.Actions.MoveToFolder.Folder = ruleFolder;
            rule.Actions.MoveToFolder.Enabled = true;

            rule.Enabled = true;

            //Save rules
            try
            {
                rules.Save(true);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

The problem I face is that the rule is created successfully in my Outlook instance.  I am able to open the Rule window in Outlook and I can see my rule.  When I open the rule, all the settings appear correct.  **However** when I run the rule it does not work.

If I  manually create an identical rule in Outlook it does work.

I have also found the following:
- Create the rule in Outlook via my C# function
- Open the rule window in Outlook
- Tick and untick a checkbox and save
- The rule runs correctly.
- Note:  If I only change the name, rather than unticking and reticking a checkbox, this does not work.
- I tried to replicate this with a hack in the code forcing this behaviour, and the rule did not work.

I wonder if there is some setting I am missing that is applied when you use the rule interface in Outlook?

Any advice would be very welcome.

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps you should try working in reverse ... create a rule in outlook, then enumerate and examine it in c# ... then you can see what's different.

Comment: Hi - thanks for your help.  I have done this comparison but unfortunately the rules seem to be identical.  Do you know if any conversion might be applied to the rule by the Outlook Rule Wizard itself?  The settings seem identical inside the two rules which is very strange. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this question.

The domain of the From email address was in a hierarchy in outlook and so not being recognized correctly.  I have included all the email addresses for the user and now the rule works.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest starting from releasing all underlying com objects in the code. Use [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.releasecomobject.aspx) to release an Outlook object when you have finished using it. Then set a variable to Nothing in Visual Basic (null in C#) to release the reference to the object.

To release all COM objects you need to break the chain of calls and declare the each property and method call on a separate line of code.

```
 OutlookApplication.Application.ActiveExplorer().Session.GetDefaultFolder
```

There is no need to call the Application property of the Application class. You have already got an instance of the Application class.

Also there is no need to call the ActiveExplorer method of the Application class. You can use the Session property or the GetNamespace method of the Application class. Review the code and release all underlying COM objects.

```
   rules.Save(true);
```

Do you get any exceptions when calling the Save method?

Anyway, I'd suggest creating a rule manually and then exploring its properties to create the same rule programmatically.